# Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].network': 'projects/xxx/global/networks/default'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create new VM using terraform in GCP , getting error. Please suggest
Note:- I don't have access to create VPC in GCP portal but i have access to create VMs machine.

```
provider "google" {
  credentials =file("xxx737191.json")
  project     = "xxx"
  region      = "us-east1"
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "virtual_instance" {
  name = "terraform-instance2"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone = "us-east1-c"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "centos-cloud/centos-7"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {}
  }

}
```

Comment: What's the error ? Can you please share it.

Comment: @abhi Please update your question by elaborating your issue with more details and the error you have faced.